# java.sql.SQLException Path to ´C:user/Usuario/Documents/javafolders.school.sqlite does not exist

Tags: android

I am writing because I created a computer base application that simple store data in a sqlite database, I used java through eclipse, the problem is that the application works fine on the  pc that it was built on as a jar file, but when I distribute the application to my people I get this message on their computer
java.sql.SQLException path to c:user//usuario/documents/school.sqlite does not exist

The question is . How to change the code tomake the application also work in other computers as well and not only on the pc that it was built on?

here is the code I used

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class sqlConnection {

    Connection conn=null;

    public static Connection dbConnector()
    {
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Documents\\workspace\\School2015.sqlite");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BIENVENIDO! Estás Conectado");
            return conn;
           }catch (Exception e)
           {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
           }

    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do myfriend ?

Comment: *"How to change the code to make the application also work in other computers as well and not only on the pc that it was built on?"* - just don't harcode path to database...

Comment: I am trying to show the application to my friends in other computers but i get the message explained above stating that database been used  does not exist because I guess is on the hard drive on the pc that the application was built on,,therefore it the application only works on my computer. I wan to change the path to to database so it can find when i run the application in another computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use 'C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\workspace\School2015.sqlite'
Use relative path instead like ..\..\..\workspace\
or if you need to set up path on runtime use it as String which should be given as input parameter to your program

Comment: Could you tell how to go on about to use a relative path instead of an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 import java.sql.*;
 import javax.swing.*;


public class sqlConnection {

Connection conn=null;

public static Connection dbConnector()
{
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Documents\\workspace\\School2015.sqlite");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "BIENVENIDO! Estás Conectado");
        return conn;
       }catch (Exception e)
       {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
       }}}
```